# Add image gallery to node in Drupal

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, gallery

I'm using Image module for Drupal 6 and the submodule of Image Gallery. Image gallery is identified by taxonomy term of certain vocabulary. What I need is to attach Image Gallery View supplied with Image Gallery to certain node. I am now trying to use Views Attach to do this. But how can I pass an argument of taxonomy term for gallery to the view? Also I added the taxonomy term for gallery to be defined for both images and my node type. Is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you drop the Image module all together and use a combination of modules to roll your own Image Gallery.  It ends up being much more flexible and extensible in my opinion.  Here is a great screencast to get you going:

http://www.lullabot.com/articles/photo-galleries-views-attach